# Align text and img inside a div

Tags: html, css

Currently doing the portfolio challenge at codecamp. I´m trying to align a text above another text, and then a img next to them. But it seems like they don´t recognize the blank space inside my div.

Here is my code

```css
#div1 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #A09F9C;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#about {
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
#avatar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p id="about">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ...</p>
  <img id="avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/scMYPYt.jpg">
  <h4> bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb </h4>
</div>
```

[This is how it's supposed to look like.](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/YqLyXB/)

If you want to take a look, [here it's my codepen.](http://codepen.io/cetaphil/pen/WxgEZX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here:

```
`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKaqbE`
```

Btw I suggest you to learn to use materialize or bootstrap for faster development.

HTML:

```
    <div id="navtab">
        <ul>
            <li class="button"><a href="#"> ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#"> PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li class="button"><a href="#"> CONTACT</a></li>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="div1">
            <p id="about"> The name is Gaston and I'm an UX/UI designeveloper, with extensive practical experience in brand strategy, creative direction and project management; devoted to Functional Programming and Information Architecture. Also a huge fan of semantics and futuristic interfaces.</p> 
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/scMYPYt.jpg">
            <div id="spdline"></div>

        </div>

        <div id="div2">
            <h4> PORTFOLIO </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="div3">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div4">
    </div>

    <div id="div5">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

#navtab {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

}

ul {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;    
    float: right;   
    margin-right: 10%;

}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;

}

li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

a {
    color: grey;    
}

a:hover {
    color: #2B303A;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:active {
    background-color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#div1 {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #A09F9C;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#about{
    padding: 10% 10%;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    float: right;
}



#spdline {
    width: 300px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;    
    display: block;

}

#div2 {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10% ;


}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Worked :). But I have another question. So, you added inline-flex in div and removed paddings in "about" right?. I've never seen inline flex in other questions posted here. It's because I use % instead of px or is something wrong in the code?

Comment: You can use % or px, that's up to you as long as you don't mess up with styling. See this for other things: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp